# can't seem to inspect modal pop up in chrome developer tools or firebug

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason I am not able to inspect a modal pop up either in chrome developer tools or firebug.

[image: pop up dialog modal box in chrome developer tools]

[image: pop up dialog modal box in firebug]

I am trying to find the source of the modal popup in order to modify the text in and around the modal. I have found the code in common.js affecting what they are calling a speedbump but cannot find the code for the text.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean the `alert()`? That's not part of the page, it's a browser control you open via JavaScript. It's been around since the early 1990s :)

Comment: Those "modals" look like browser alerts, not javascript/html modals.  I doubt you can control those at all.

Comment: @Becuzz They are modal browser alerts, but you can modify that on their HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code of the page

```
<div id="speedbump">
     <span class="internal"><p>The page you are going to on usbank.com is not optimized for viewing on a mobile device.</p></span>
     <div class="continue">Continue</div>
     <div class="cancel">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

They are using a confirm dialog, but the HTML is right there.

---

People don't believe me... so here is a picture, take a look now :D

http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/108/nowyousee.png

Comment: This might be an alternative control for the same purpose, but it cannot be related to the dialogues the OP is asking about.

Comment: Are you sure about that ? take a look on the image I will upload :D

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario take a look now bro :D

Comment: That picture demonstrates that there's JavaScript code on the page that reads that DOM node and populates a `confirm()` browser control with its content. While it's a nice finding (it is), it doesn't really answer the original question: the dialogue that pops up in the screen is neither HTML nor part of the DOM, thus it cannot be *inspected*. The question is about the "modal" itself, not the source of its data.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Not answer the question ? "...I am trying to find the source of the modal popup in order to modify the text in and around the modal... ...cannot find the code for the text."

Comment: Not sure what "around" means in this context (I assumed it referred to the dialogue title) but you are right, your answer is pretty close to that description. You've got my upvote ;-)

Comment: Hi Guys. Thank you so much for your response. In this case I am called upon to change the text in the chrome portion above the dialog box itself. Sorry for the ambiguity.